# search for a large set of tokens across a large set of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm working in SQL Server 2008.  I'm trying to return all records where the given columns have a substring that matches at least one token of a very large set of tokens.  The number of columns I'm searching on is also quite large.  What is the best way to do this?

I know that the basic approach is something like:

```
WHERE  
    (col1 LIKE '%token1%' OR col1 LIKE '%token2%' OR...  
     OR  
     col2 LIKE '%token1%' OR col1 LIKE '%token2%' OR...  
     OR  
     .  . . .
    )
```

However, this will be very tedious and large.

Comment: I'm wondering if it would help to append all the columns together and search that string instead of each individual column.

Comment: Yes, I can certainly concatenate the columns (with a delimiter separating each).  But, I still have the problem of searching for many tokens.

Comment: can you put all of your tokens (STREET, DRIVE, AVENUE) in a table, with one token for each row, then iterate through the rows to find the matches?  Not exactly sure what you're doing, do you want to replace the tokens with a standard abbreviation?

Comment: I could.  I'm simply trying to return all records where a full word was used instead of its abbreviation.  (See below.)

Comment: if you use the table and a cursor, for example, you won't have so much code to write.  is that what you're trying to optimize for, or do you want to modify the value in the source column, for example, before deduping?  anyways, if I were you, I'd put the updated value in another column or table with a 1-1 relationship so you never modify the original.  your code could get buggy and you don't want to lose your source data.

Comment: performance is going to suck with a cursor, though. not sure what you're optimizing for or what you're concerned about, other than writing a lot of code.

Comment: I'm not concerned about performance.  Since the list of tokens is quite large, I'm leaning toward using a cursor.  I'm not trying to modify any source data.  I just want to return records where some portion of the text in each column matches any of the tokens in a list (i.e., a table of the tokens).

Comment: I'm asking about the larger purpose.  Why do you want to identify them?  What's the next step in the process?  Is it to identify unique mailing addresses without duplicates introduced by the tokens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.

You basically have two alternatives.  The first is full text search.  That is, treat each column as a document and create a full text index on them.

The second option is to normalize your data structure.  You would create a separate row for each token in each column.  A row in this normalized structure would look like:

```
EntityId      "Column"     Token
    1           col1       Toke1
    1           col3       Toke2
    2           col1       Toke2
 . . .
```

This structure would greatly speed your search with the appropriate index.

By the way, your data structure looks suspicious.  A table that contains lists of things in a column is usually a bad idea.  The proper data structure for a list in relational databases is a table, not a column.  A table with multiple columns that contain the same type of information (such as a list of tokens) usually suggests that the columns should be denormalized.

Comment: Actually, my table contains customer addresses.  It's mostly normalized in the sense that street info is always in the Street column, country values are always in the Country column, etc.  However, there could be records where street info is, say, in the Country column.  So, I have to treat each column as if it can hold any data element (which is why I need to search over all columns).  I'm trying to determine where certain tokens were not abbreviated.  For instance, I need to determine where 'STREET' was used instead of 'ST'.  There are lots of tokens I need to search on.

Comment: @user3100444 . . . It sounds like you need to spend a few days cleaning up the data.  Having the "Street" sometimes be in the "Country" column is dangerous.

Comment: Right.  However, I don't control what gets entered into this table.  I'm simply trying to determine where full words were used instead of abbreviations.

Comment: But how do you distinguish "ST" meaning "street" from "ST" as an abbreviation for "Sao Tome and Principe"?